# Move Mail from Sender to Sender's Folder Name

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to move messages from the sender to the folder I created for the sender.

The SenderName is displayed as "Doe, John (US)" and my folder would be "Doe, John".

What do I need to do to compare the SenderName to a subfolder name that is two levels below **`"Inbox". I.e. Inbox→Folder1→"Doe, John".`**

```
Public Sub MoveToFolder()
Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim objNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim objSourceFolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim currentExplorer As Explorer
Dim Selection As Selection
Dim obj As Object

Dim objSubfolder As Outlook.Folder
Dim olsubFolder As Outlook.Folder

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem

Dim objVariant As Variant
Dim lngMovedItems As Long
Dim intCount As Integer

Set objOutlook = Application
Set objNameSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set currentExplorer = objOutlook.ActiveExplorer
Set Selection = currentExplorer.Selection
Set objSourceFolder = currentExplorer.CurrentFolder
Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set olFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olFolder = olFolder.Folders("Inbox")
Set colFolders = objParentFolder.Folders

For Each obj In Selection
    Set objVariant = obj

    Dim sfName As Object
    Set sfName = Left(objVariant.senderName, Len(objVariant.senderName) - 5)

    If objVariant.Class = olMail Then

        On Error Resume Next
        ' Use These lines if the destination folder
        '  is not a subfolder of the current folder
        For Each objSubfolder In colFolders
            For Each olsubFolder In objSubfolder
                If olsubFolder.Name = sfName Then
                    Set objDestFolder = objSubfolder
                    MsgBox "Ductus Exemplo"
                    'objVariant.Move objDestFolder
                    'count the # of items moved
                    lngMovedItems = lngMovedItems + 1
                     'Display the number of items that were moved.
                    MsgBox "Moved " & lngMovedItems & " messages(s) from  " & _
                    sfName & "to " & objDestFolder
                Else
                    If objDestFolder Is Nothing Then
                        MsgBox "No Folder Found for " & sfName
                        'Set objDestFolder = objSourceFolder.Folders.Add(sfName)
                        Exit Sub
                    End If

            Next
        Next
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: For bounty hunters, now that I made a comment here, you can use @Tyop if you want to draw my attention.

Comment: The question is unclear (at least to me :)). It seems to me that you want something like [Rules](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-email-messages-by-using-rules-c24f5dea-9465-4df4-ad17-a50704d66c59). How do rules differ from the goal of the question?

Comment: @dee My interpretation is "Doe, John (US)" is an example of the format. There are an unknown number of senders where " (US)" has been appended to the sender name. This is why the OP has incorporated Set sfName = Left(objVariant.senderName, Len(objVariant.senderName) - 5) to remove the suffix, rather than moving the mail by rule to the "Doe, John" folder. Even if the OP created folders that included " (US)" there would still be multiple senders to sort into the corresponding subfolders.

Comment: The OP's code indicates the mail will be selected. Mail should not be processed as it arrives.

Comment: I have my Outlook inbox organized by sub-folders (groups); within those sub-folders are individual folders for each person. The folder names are structured like their Outlook names are. I.e., Last Name, First Name, Middle Initial, Country Code (Middle Initial and country code are not used in my folders). 
The suggested code creates a folder (Folder1) with the correct sub-folder format (last name, first name) and moves the mail item to said folder, but I need it to move it to an existing folder with that senders name.

Comment: So, the first level under Inbox are **Group Names**, then 2nd level are **Sender's Name** where mails will be moved to. Is it right to assume all sender names are unique? i.e. assuming no people in your circle has the same first and last name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Assumptions

- The sender subfolders will be two levels below inbox but not under a single parent folder (i.e. "Doe, John" could appear under Folder1 and "Doe, Jane" under Folder2)
- All emails that should be processed by the macro will be selected before executing it
- The code should not create subfolders for missing senders - as there are multiple possible "parent" folders - but should output a message containing a list of missing sender folders

*Conditions that trigger the end of a sender name:*

- A hyphen following or preceding a space (i.e. "Doe, John - US" = "Doe, John" and "Huntington-Whiteley, Rosie - CAN" = Huntington-Whiteley, Rosie")
- The second instance of a comma (i.e. "Doe, John, CPA" = "Doe, John")
- The second instance of a space (i.e. "Doe, John Q" = "Doe, John")
- An apostrophe preceded or followed by a space (i.e. "O'Leary, John" = "O'Leary, John" but "Doe, John 'US'" = "Doe, John")
- Any other non-alphabetical character (i.e. "Doe, John: US" = "Doe, John"

---

### Proposed Solution

This code will satisfy all of the above conditions, and will output a single message at the end denoting any senders for whom folders could not be found (as opposed to a separate message for each email). It has been tested on Outlook 2013/Windows 10.

```
Public Sub MoveToFolder()

Dim objSelection As Selection
Set objSelection = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection

Dim iSelected As Integer, iMoved As Integer
iSelected = objSelection.Count 'Get a total for output message

Dim StrOutput As String, StrUnmoved As String, StrName As String
StrUnmoved = "Unmoved Item Count by Sender" & vbNewLine & "============================"

Dim objNS As NameSpace
Dim objParentFolder As Folder, objSubFolder As Folder, objDestFolder As Folder
Dim BFound As Boolean, iLoc As Integer
Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objParentFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

'Only execute code if the parent folder has subfolders
If objParentFolder.Folders.Count > 0 Then
    'Loop through all selected items
    For Each Item In objSelection
        If Item.Class = 43 Then
            'This is an email.
            BFound = False
            StrName = GetSenderName(Item.SenderName)
            For Each objSubFolder In objParentFolder.Folders
                If objSubFolder.Folders.Count > 0 Then
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Set objDestFolder = Nothing
                    Set objDestFolder = objSubFolder.Folders(StrName)
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    If Not objDestFolder Is Nothing Then
                        'Folder found.
                        Item.Move objDestFolder
                        iMoved = iMoved + 1
                        BFound = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            If Not BFound Then
                'Sender folder not found. Check if we have already logged this sender.
                iLoc = 0
                iLoc = InStr(1, StrUnmoved, StrName)
                If iLoc > 0 Then
                    'Existing sender name. Increment current total.
                    StrUnmoved = Left(StrUnmoved, iLoc + Len(StrName) + 1) & _
                    Format(CInt(Mid(StrUnmoved, iLoc + Len(StrName) + 2, 5)) + 1, "00000") & Right(StrUnmoved, Len(StrUnmoved) - iLoc - Len(StrName) - 6)
                Else
                    'New sender name.
                    StrUnmoved = StrUnmoved & vbNewLine & StrName & ": 00001"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If iMoved = iSelected Then
        StrOutput = "All " & iSelected & " items moved to appropriate subfolders."
    Else
        'Remove extraneous zeroes
        StrUnmoved = Replace(StrUnmoved, ": 000", ": ")
        StrUnmoved = Replace(StrUnmoved, ": 00", ": ")
        StrUnmoved = Replace(StrUnmoved, ": 0", ": ")
        StrOutput = iMoved & "/" & iSelected & " items moved to appropriate subfolders; see below for unmoved details." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & StrUnmoved
    End If
    MsgBox StrOutput
Else
    MsgBox "There are no subfolders to the default inbox. Script will now exit."
End If

End Sub

Function GetSenderName(StrFullSender As String) As String

'Only take action if a non-null string is passed
If Len(StrFullSender) > 1 Then
    StrFullSender = Trim(StrFullSender) 'Trim extraneous spaces
    Dim StrOutput As String
    'Find first case of the end of the name
    Dim iChar As Integer
    Dim iCommaCount As Integer
    Dim iSpaceCount As Integer
    For iChar = 1 To Len(StrFullSender)
        Select Case Asc(Mid(StrFullSender, iChar, 1))
            Case 65 To 90, 97 To 122 '192 to 246, 248 to 255 'Include 192-246 and 248-255 if you will receive emails from senders with accents or other symbols in their names
                'No action necessary - this is a letter
            Case 45, 151 'Hyphen or EM Dash - could be a hyphenated name
                If Mid(StrFullSender, IIf(iChar = 1, 1, iChar - 1), IIf(Len(StrFullSender) - iChar > 1, 3, Len(StrFullSender) - iChar + 1)) <> _
                    Trim(Mid(StrFullSender, IIf(iChar = 1, 1, iChar - 1), IIf(Len(StrFullSender) - iChar > 1, 3, Len(StrFullSender) - iChar + 1))) Then Exit For
                    'There is a space on one or both sides of the hyphen. This is a valid stop.
            Case 44
                iCommaCount = iCommaCount + 1
                If iCommaCount > 1 Then Exit For
            Case 32
                iSpaceCount = iSpaceCount + 1
                If iSpaceCount > 1 Then Exit For
            Case 39
                If Mid(StrFullSender, IIf(iChar = 1, 1, iChar - 1), IIf(Len(StrFullSender) - iChar > 1, 3, Len(StrFullSender) - iChar + 1)) <> _
                    Trim(Mid(StrFullSender, IIf(iChar = 1, 1, iChar - 1), IIf(Len(StrFullSender) - iChar > 1, 3, Len(StrFullSender) - iChar + 1))) Then Exit For
                    'There is a space on one or both sides of the apostrophe. This is a valid stop.
            Case Else
                Exit For
        End Select
    Next

    StrOutput = Trim(Left(StrFullSender, iChar - 1))

    GetSenderName = StrOutput
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Tested in Outlook 2010, Windows 7 and worked flawlessly.

Comment: I did discover that if the SenderName is "Smith, W L" the code will not move the message to the folder because of the second initial being in the folder name. I.e. the folder name has to be changed from "Smith, W L" to "Smith, W" in order for the message to be moved.

Comment: Ah. That's a side effect of trimming the sender name after the second space, which was intended to remove middle initials. It would be possible to add additional logic to the check whereby the second space only ends the sanitized sender name if the previous word is longer than one character, but that depends on how crucial this feature is to you.

Answer (score 2):

The goal appears to be organizing selected mail items based on the SenderName when invoked.

Have put a bit further as you can move items within a folder of choice when nothing in selection moved (ie. selected meeting items only).

When picking a folder to process items, the folder cannot be the main sub folder or it's child folders.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const SUB_FDR As String = "Folder1" ' The name of main sub-folder under Inbox to move mails to

Sub MoveSenderToFolder()
    Dim oNS As NameSpace, oMainFDR As Folder, oSubFDR As Folder
    Dim oItem As Variant, iMoved As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If oNS Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Cannot get MAPI namespace from Outlook! Abortting!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "MoveSenderToFolder()"
    Else
        ' Proceed to Set Folders
        Set oMainFDR = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
        ' Get the sub folder "SUB_FDR" under Inbox
        If Not oMainFDR Is Nothing Then Set oSubFDR = GetSubFolder(oMainFDR, SUB_FDR)
        If oSubFDR Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Cannot get the main sub folder """ & SUB_FDR & """ under """ & oMainFDR.Name & """"
        Else
            iMoved = 0
            ' [1] Process the Selected items
            For Each oItem In ActiveExplorer.Selection
                MoveItemToFolder oItem, oSubFDR, iMoved
            Next
            ' [2] Ask to process a Folder if no MailItems are moved from Selection
            If iMoved = 0 Then
                If vbYes = MsgBox("Would you like to select a folder to move mail items?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "MoveSenderToFolder()") Then
                    Set oMainFDR = oNS.PickFolder ' Reuse oMainFDR object to the selected folder
                    ' Only proceed if it's a folder not within Main Sub folder.
                    If Len(Replace(oMainFDR.FolderPath, oSubFDR.FolderPath, "")) = Len(oMainFDR.FolderPath) Then
                        For Each oItem In oMainFDR.Items
                            MoveItemToFolder oItem, oSubFDR, iMoved
                        Next
                    Else
                        MsgBox "Will not process folder/subfolders of the main folder """ & SUB_FDR & """", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "MoveSenderToFolder()"
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            Set oSubFDR = Nothing
            Set oMainFDR = Nothing
        End If
        Set oNS = Nothing
        MsgBox iMoved & " item(s) are moved.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "MoveSenderToFolder()"
    End If
End Sub

' Move input item to a sub folder and increment counter
Private Sub MoveItemToFolder(ByRef oItem As Variant, ByRef oSubFDR As Folder, ByRef iMoved As Long)
    Dim oMail As MailItem, sName As String, oTargetFDR As Folder
    If TypeName(oItem) = "MailItem" Then
        Set oMail = oItem
        sName = GetSenderName(oMail)
        Set oTargetFDR = GetSubFolder(oSubFDR, sName)
        If oTargetFDR Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Cannot get Target folder """ & oSubFDR.FolderPath & "\" & sName & """"
        Else
            oMail.Move oTargetFDR
            iMoved = iMoved + 1
        End If
        Set oMail = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

' Extract the Sender Name before any brackets
Private Function GetSenderName(ByRef oItem As MailItem) As String
    Dim sName As String
    sName = oItem.SenderName
    If InStr(1, sName, "(", vbTextCompare) > 1 Then sName = Split(sName, "(")(0)
    If InStr(1, sName, "<", vbTextCompare) > 1 Then sName = Split(sName, "<")(0)
    If InStr(1, sName, "[", vbTextCompare) > 1 Then sName = Split(sName, "[")(0)
    If InStr(1, sName, "{", vbTextCompare) > 1 Then sName = Split(sName, "{")(0)
    GetSenderName = Trim(sName)
End Function

' Given a name, get the sub-folder object from a main folder (create if required)
Private Function GetSubFolder(ByRef oParentFDR As Folder, ByVal sName As String) As Folder
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim oFDR As Folder
    Set oFDR = oParentFDR.Folders(sName)
    If oFDR Is Nothing Then Set oFDR = oParentFDR.Folders.Add(sName)
    Set GetSubFolder = oFDR
End Function
```

---

**CODE UPDATE based on OP's comment**

Searches all the sub folders within Inbox for the Sender's Name. If not found, prompts to create from Folder Picker.

```
Option Explicit

Private oNS As NameSpace

Sub MoveSenderToFolder()
    Dim oMainFDR As Folder, oSubFDR As Folder
    Dim oItem As Variant, iMoved As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If oNS Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Cannot get MAPI namespace from Outlook! Abortting!", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "MoveSenderToFolder()"
    Else
        ' Proceed to Set Folders
        Set oMainFDR = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
        If Not oMainFDR Is Nothing Then
            iMoved = 0
            ' [1] Process the Selected items
            For Each oItem In ActiveExplorer.Selection
                MoveItemToFolder oItem, oMainFDR, iMoved
            Next
            ' [2] Ask to process a Folder if no MailItems are moved from Selection
            If iMoved = 0 Then
                If vbYes = MsgBox("Would you like to select a folder to move mail items?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "MoveSenderToFolder()") Then
                    Set oSubFDR = oNS.PickFolder ' Reuse oMainFDR object to the selected folder
                    For Each oItem In oSubFDR.Items
                        MoveItemToFolder oItem, oMainFDR, iMoved
                    Next
                    Set oSubFDR = Nothing
                End If
            End If
            Set oSubFDR = Nothing
            Set oMainFDR = Nothing
        End If
        Set oNS = Nothing
        MsgBox iMoved & " item(s) are moved.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "MoveSenderToFolder()"
    End If
End Sub

' Get Folder object based on a Name and a root folder
Private Function GetSenderFolder(ByRef oRootFDR As Folder, ByVal sName As String) As Folder
    Dim oFDR As Folder, oFDR2 As Folder
    For Each oFDR In oRootFDR.Folders
        If oFDR.Name = sName Then
            Set oFDR2 = oFDR
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If oFDR Is Nothing Then
        For Each oFDR In oRootFDR.Folders
            Set oFDR2 = GetSenderFolder(oFDR, sName)
            If Not oFDR2 Is Nothing Then Exit For
        Next
    End If
    Set GetSenderFolder = oFDR2
End Function

' Move input item (Mail Items only) to a sub folder and increment counter
Private Sub MoveItemToFolder(ByRef oItem As Variant, ByRef oRootFDR As Folder, ByRef iMoved As Long)
    Dim oMail As MailItem, sName As String, oTargetFDR As Folder
    If TypeName(oItem) = "MailItem" Then
        Set oMail = oItem
        sName = GetSenderName(oMail)
        Set oTargetFDR = GetSenderFolder(oRootFDR, sName)
        If oTargetFDR Is Nothing Then
            If vbYes = MsgBox("Cannot get Target folder """ & oRootFDR.FolderPath & "\" & sName & """" & vbLf & _
                "Would you like to create the folder from folder of your choice?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) Then
                Set oTargetFDR = CreateSubFolder(sName)
            End If
        End If
        If Not oTargetFDR Is Nothing Then
            oMail.Move oTargetFDR
            iMoved = iMoved + 1
        End If
        Set oMail = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

' Extract the Sender Name before any brackets
Private Function GetSenderName(ByRef oItem As MailItem) As String
    Dim sName As String
    sName = oItem.SenderName
    If InStr(1, sName, "(", vbTextCompare) > 1 Then sName = Split(sName, "(")(0)
    If InStr(1, sName, "<", vbTextCompare) > 1 Then sName = Split(sName, "<")(0)
    If InStr(1, sName, "[", vbTextCompare) > 1 Then sName = Split(sName, "[")(0)
    If InStr(1, sName, "{", vbTextCompare) > 1 Then sName = Split(sName, "{")(0)
    GetSenderName = Trim(sName)
End Function

' Given a name, Create the sub-folder object from Folder Picker
Private Function CreateSubFolder(ByVal sName As String) As Folder
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim oFDR As Folder
    Set oFDR = oNS.PickFolder
    If Not oFDR Is Nothing Then Set oFDR = oFDR.Folders.Add(sName)
    Set CreateSubFolder = oFDR
End Function
```

Comment: Great solution - I like the addition of a feature to create the folder in a user-specified location if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank @NickPeranzi. I always put myself into the same situation and think a little further on what may come up to help. You may also want to put `LCase()` for folder name comparison in **GetSenderFolder**: `If LCase(oFDR.Name) = LCase(sName) Then`

Answer (score 0):

Update Folder Name `Folders("Folder1")`

```
Option Explicit
Sub File_olItems()
    Dim olNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olSourceFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim olDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim currentExplorer As Explorer
    Dim Selection As Selection
    Dim olItem As MailItem
    Dim vItem As Variant
    Dim NameSender As String
    Dim i As Long

    Set olNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set currentExplorer = Application.ActiveExplorer
    Set Selection = currentExplorer.Selection
    Set olSourceFolder = olNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Folder1")

    For Each olItem In Selection
        Set vItem = olItem

        If vItem.Class = olMail Then
            Debug.Print vItem.SentOnBehalfOfName
            NameSender = vItem.SentOnBehalfOfName

            If NameSender = ";" Then
                NameSender = vItem.SenderName
            End If

            If InStr(1, NameSender, "(", vbTextCompare) > 1 Then
                NameSender = Split(NameSender, "(")(0)
                Debug.Print NameSender
            End If

            On Error Resume Next
            Set olDestFolder = olSourceFolder.Folders(NameSender)

            If olDestFolder Is Nothing Then
                Set olDestFolder = olSourceFolder.Folders.Add(NameSender)
            End If

            vItem.Move olDestFolder
'           // count items moved
            i = i + 1
            Set olDestFolder = Nothing
        End If
    Next olItem

'   // Display the number of items that were moved.
    MsgBox "Moved " & i & " Mail Items."

    Set currentExplorer = Nothing
    Set olItem = Nothing
    Set Selection = Nothing
    Set olNameSpace = Nothing
    Set olSourceFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```